# How to select all tables from access database into new pivottable

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a pivottable where I can screen through all the different tables I have in my access database. E.g I have different data for stocks: "Elux", "Alfa", "Third" etc etc. I would like to have them all show up in a pivottable, as of now I have only managed to create a pivottable for a single table through VBA.

When doing it manually with macro recordset I get the below code, macro recorder has issues with the double quotes and also the statement does not update if one adds a new table to the databse and hit refresh on the pivottable.

Anyone got any ideas? What I would like to have is an SQL query which basically is: SELECT * FROM all tables, but I couldn't find a way when googling.

Update: So I tried with "SELECT * FROM Instruments, Geti  " but the issue is that I can't get the neat view then where I can collapse the corresponding fields to the table, everything is just in a mess then.

Code from macro recordet

```
Sub Tester
    Sheets.Add
    Workbooks("YQL.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "DataBase", "", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password=;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\DataBase.accdb;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=;Jet OLEDB:System database=;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLE" & _
        "atabase Password=;Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False", """" & _
        "ASS"
,""X"",""GETI"",""Instruments"",""SWED"",""YHOO""", 6, TRUE, FALSE
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("DataBase"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable7" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It's impossible to pivot all tables in database!

Comment: Your DB would be easier to manage if all stock info was in the same table, with a foreign key to a "stocks" table.  If you want to keep separate tables then create a view in your DB using UNION ALL to join the data from all the tables.

Comment: But the excel macro recorder does it.... just not in a very flexible way.